# How to change RepositoryItem without using CustomRowCellEdit?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I would like to change RepositoryItem in diffrent way than shown in the code bellow. Motivation to do this is described in [obsolete field CustomRowCellEditEventArgs.RowHandle](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q329152/customcolumndataeventargs-rowhandle-is-obsolete).

```
private void GridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;

    if (e.Column.FieldName == CONSTS_FIELD_NAME)
    {
        var val = (VAL_TYPE) view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, CONSTS_FIELD_NAME);
        if (val == VAL_VALUE)
            e.RepositoryItem = new RepositoryItem(); // setting new Repository Item
    }
}
```

So I decided to use this code:

```
private void GridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;

    if (e.Column.FieldName == CONSTS_FIELD_NAME)
    {
        var result = view.GetSelectedRows();
        var val = (VAL_TYPE) view.GetRowCellValue(result.First(), CONSTS_FIELD_NAME);
        if (val == VAL_VALUE)
            e.RepositoryItem = new RepositoryItem(); // setting new Repository Item
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to change RepositoryItem using some events?

Answer (score 1):

The situation with [CustomColumnDataEventArgs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData.event) you mentioned(providing unbound data for the specific column) have no relation with GridView's editing process. When the CustomRowCellEdit event is fired all the row handles are already calculated. Thus there is no motivation to avoid the first approach.
The only recommendation I can suggest is to **use the predefined repository item instead of creating a new one** every time:

```
void GridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if(e.Column.FieldName == CONSTS_FIELD_NAME) {
        var val = (VAL_TYPE)view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, CONSTS_VAL);
        if(val == VAL_VALUE)
            e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemForVAL_VALUE; 
    }
}
```

To use a specific editor **for inplace-editing only**, you should handle the [CustomRowCellEditForEditing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEditForEditing.event) event.

Please also carefully read the Remarks section of the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event) event documentation which clearly describes how this event works.